# Sens de choupinou

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

J'ai vu le mot « choupinou » utilisé en ligne pour décrire l'histoire et l'art d'un *anime* (animation japonaise). Ça a l'air positif, mais qu'est-ce que ça veut dire et comment peut-on l'utiliser ?

Est-ce qu'il s'agit d'argot français (c'est-à-dire de France)?

CLARIFICATION: « choupinou » était employé comme adjectif : « L'histoire est trop choupinou ». Pourtant, les commentaires ci-dessous montrent qu'il est possible de l'utiliser comme substantif : « mon choupinou/ma choupinette ».

Comment: Normalement : terme informel qui veut dire *mignon*, *petit mignon*, dérivation sans doute de *chou*, reconnu depuis plus longtemps. (Je ne sais rien du rapport avec l'anime.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ça a l'air d'être exactement la réponse que je cherche! Et je suppose que c'est l'argot de français de France, au lieu de français canadien par exemple?

Comment: Je crois que c'est plus courant en France. Lors d'une recherche sur Google je vois que ceux qui en parlent sont des français (e.g. [ici](http://ow.ly/3OYW30aEedi) : France, Belgique, etc). Mais il faudra attendre l'avis de l'un des européens ou des québecois qui fréquentent ce site. :)

Comment: Vient de *choupinet* (*chou* + *poupinet*). Bonne réponse de Luke. Un peu l'équivalent de *kawaii*.

Comment: @LukeSawczak En effet, c'est *très* européen comme mot. Un Québécois dirait juste que c'est *cute*.

Comment: Très choupinou cette question !

Comment: @LukeSawczak *choupinou* est un substantif, pas un adjectif comme *cute*. On peut dire en France « qu'il est gentil, mon choupinou » mais je ne sais pas si « qu'il est gentil, mon cute » est possible.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vrai. J'essayais de communiquer cette idée avec "petit mignon" mais c'est difficile de deviner son statut à partir de ça ... ma version originale en anglais était : "little cute/adorable *one*".

Comment: Mes amis qui parlent le français de Congo et d'île Maurice m'a dit qu'ils n'avaient jamais entendu "chopinou". Mon amie d'île Maurice a suggeré qu'elle a entendu "trognon" comme combinaison de "trop" et "mignon".

Comment: @tamayura Ils connaissent peut-être poupinou/poupinette ?

Comment: @tamayura Comme je suis très pointilleux avec la langue française, je me permets deux petites remarques... D'abord, « online » s'écrit en deux mots en français : « en ligne ». Ensuite, je vous invite à prendre connaissance des règles typographiques en français. Elles sont très différentes de ce que vous connaissez en anglais... Concernant votre question stricto sensu, « choupinou » est un mot appartenant au registre familier signifiant « mignon ». C'est un qualificatif assez fréquemment employé par les femmes devant un bébé. ^^

Comment: @Badacadabra Merci pour les corrections. Pourtant, pouvez-vous clarifier ce que vous voulez dire par "règles typographiques"?

Comment: @jlliagre Vous avez dit que "choupinou" est plutôt un substantif, mais le commentaire que j'ai vu en ligne était de type: "l'histoire est très choupinou" - c'était employé comme adjectif

Comment: About typographical conventions, see https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/148/1109 , About *choupinou* nature, it can indeed also be used as an invariable adjective just like *chou*; e.g.: *Il est très chou mon chou !* See http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chou

Comment: @tamayura Bien sûr... Tout d'abord, les guillemets français sont `«»` en lieu et place de `""` (qui sont des guillemets anglais). En outre, certains caractères de ponctuation tels que `:;!?` doivent être précédés d'une espace, de préférence insécable (ce qui n'est pas forcément simple à mettre en œuvre sur le Web, celui-ci étant plutôt optimisé pour la typographie anglaise). Pour le point et la virgule, les règles sont cependant les mêmes qu'en anglais. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puisqu'aucune autre interprétation n'a été suggérée, je reformule mon commentaire pour en faire une réponse :

*Choupinou* ne semble figurer que dans très peu de dictionnaires, dont [Reverso Context](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/choupinou?utm_source=reversoweb&utm_medium=contextresults&utm_campaign=resultpage) et [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/choupinou), mais pas [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/choupinou) ni [Reverso Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/choupinou) ni le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choupinou) ni [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/choupinou) ni ceux qui sont représentés dans le [DVLF](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/choupinou). Le terme est également absent dans mon Robert version imprimée. C'est surprenant vu que tout le monde semble le reconnaître !

En effet, le mot est parmi de nombreuses dérivations créées sur la base du mot familier et très courant *chou* qui veut dire : quelque chose de *mignon*, *chéri*, *adorable*. À comparer avec *chouchou*, *chouette*, etc. (Digression : depuis que j'ai regardé « Le pont de la rivière Kwai », le mot *adorable* me rappelle systématiquement la scène qu'on retrouve à 2:05:55 en suivant [ce lien](https://youtu.be/nqQF4RvfOOc?t=2h5m55s).)

La forme dérivée ici est un substantif, p.ex. « mon choupinou » . Le morphème *-inou* est décrit dans [ce fil WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/choupinou.118690/) comme diminutif ( « mon petit chou » ) étant donc égal au morphème *-inet* dont le sens est identique. On y donne aussi la forme féminine *choupinette*. Comme jlliagre le rapporte, il y a d'autres mots ainsi dérivés : *poupinou* (de *poupée*), *lapinou* (de *lapin* évidemment), et leurs formes féminines, qui ont tous les même connotations.

Comme ont dit les autres dans les commentaires, *choupinou* semble être courant en France/Europe.

Je ne trouve rien sur le rapport avec l'anime, hors la caractérisation usuelle des personnages. :)

Comment: Merci, @jlliagre. Those were some careless mistakes on my part!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I didn't change *argot* but I think it is not the right term here. *Chou* is not *argot* but a familiar term like "honey/sweetheart" in English, and not used as an adjective (*mignon*) but a substantive. *Choupinou* has several very similar synonyms like *poupinou*, *lapinou* and the feminine *choupinette*, *poupinette*, *lapinette*.

Comment: @jlliagre Révisé.

Comment: On a aussi "choupinette" au féminin.

Comment: Sur le rapport avec l'animé, surtout l'animé Japonais, il faut bien entendu le rapprocher de *kawaii* comme Simon Déchamps le suggère dans son commentaire. On pourra objecter que par exemple *mignon* eut été équivalent, mais *choupinet* appartient à un champ lexical plus... choupinet.

Comment: @Frank Oui, *choupinette* était déjà mentionné dans un commentaire précédent.

Answer (score 4):

Il faut réaliser que choupinet/choupinette peuvent s'obtenir de l'inversion de pichounet/pichounette, pichou devenant choupi. En Verlan, procédé argotique, on vire tout à l'envers. Choupi, choupinette sont des termes affectueux *généralement* réservés aux enfants.  Les termes "mignon/mignonne" sont très proches, voire équivalents.